# Operating Pi in below zero temperatures?

Tags: pi-3, boot, sd-card

I have a few RPi3s and have noticed that any time I attempt to operate any of them in temperatures below -12C they fail to boot up properly. Sometimes the boot process fails at the command line after entering the start command and it reports that no file system exists and other times it will start to boot into the OS but portions of the OS fail to load. Either way requires a power cycle or two to heat it up enough to function properly. I am guessing it may be related to the SD card but I have also tried numerous brands and sizes without a different result. I also see that someone has run the Pi in liquid nitrogen and it seemed to work fine... Has anyone else experienced the low-temp failures I have and if so perhaps you have a few ideas to stop them from failing as I intend to use them often in sub-zero temperatures.

Comment: have you considered it may be the power supply?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had thought about that around a year ago. Swapped out the power supply numerous times but also no change in result. I don't see the square rainbow in the screen that points to low power. Just the same though, for the sake of being clear on what I have. I am using a 9-35V to 5V 5A DC step down converter connected directly to the Pi and a 12v 220AH AGM battery bank at full charge. I also considered the battery bank being affected by the cold but metering it shows it is at full capacity.

Comment: What part of your equipment is below freezing point? Actually RPi is specified to be used from 0 to 50C. However I have read that someguys put it in the liquid nitrogen and it still worked. Did you try to replace your SD card?

Comment: Roman, you should probably reread the OP ;)